# Uber Live Driver Route GPS Update

Tags: ios, geolocation, live

I am getting into ioS development.  Does anyone know how apps like Uber achieve live gps updates of driver's en route?  You can see exactly where the driver is on the map and it's a live feed.

Can this be achieved through use of Google Maps API?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, all they need is that the Driver has a device which has GPS and internet connection. Then the device locates itself (periodically) and sends the location to the central server, in which the location along side information identifying the car is stored.

And then the map view simply fetches the data from the database and shows the cars in the Map. And again it simply refreshes the data with timer.

So the Google Maps API, alongside with any other Maps offering can indeed be used for showing the map and the cars in it. But for the positioning parts, as well as for the server side implementations you likely would need to search for other offerings as well.